# IIS use wrong pt-PT

Tags: c#, iis, globalization, windows-10

In .net 4.0, web forms and IIS 8
I have in web.config this:

```
<globalization culture="pt-PT" uiCulture="pt-PT" />
```

When I do in C# this:

```
ltNumber.Text = (12345.12).ToString("N");
```

I get this: `12 345,12`
But the output must be `12.345,12`

This began to look bad on windows 10. windows 7 everything was fine. What can be wrong?

Comment: In web.config I have: globalization culture="pt-PT" uiCulture="pt-PT"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The numeric (`"N"`) format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString) uses your `CurrentCulture` settings.

That means your `CurrentCulture` has white space as a [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0xh94xt(v=vs.110).aspx) and `,` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b74zyt45(v=vs.110).aspx).

[image]

As a solution, you can [`Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone.aspx) your `CurrentCulture`, set these properties what ever you want, and use *that* culture as a second parameter in your `ToString` method. Like;

```
var clone = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
clone.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
ltNumber.Text = (12345.12).ToString("N", clone); // 12.345,12
```

I don't think these properties are changed based on operating system versions. It all about which culture settings you use.

Comment: Well, it's a possible solution, but I think it does not make sense because they experiment with IIS Express, NumberGroupSeparator appears with the point. In addition, on win7 it was okay. I think it is a problem in IIS. How do you explain that?

Comment: When using IIS Express, it is using your user's number format settings and you must have changed the `Digit grouping symbol` to a dot. The system default for pt-PT is a space